# ASP.NET / IIS Security (Windows Authentication)

Tags: asp.net, windows, security, authentication, iis

This will probably turn out to be a doozie.

I'm developing an application in ASP.NET to be put on our company's intranet site. I've been handed a specification in regards to security and have no idea how to do it.

First part: The application is to use Windows Authentication. This part seems easy enough; I  opened IIS in Administrative Tools, right clicked the node of my website, properties and checked 'Integrate Windows Authentication'. However, I have no idea how I will govern which people have access to my site. I'm thinking this should be taken care of at the database level. This is Q#1

Second part -- I have to implement a process for the following scenario: User 'Jane' can log in to our network, but does not have rights to my application. User 'Bob' does have rights to use my application. Bob needs to be able to sit at Jane's computer (under her network account), but be able to enter his credentials into my application and use it (even though Jane is logged into the local machine and network). This is Q#2

Any help, general direction, or advice would be appreciated. The winning lottery numbers would be appreciated even more.

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: if Bob (at Jane's computer) is logged into the local machine and network as Jane, wouldn't the application see Bob as Jane if you are using Windows Authentication?

Comment: Yup, that's what I have to work around.

Comment: Upon opening the app, can you just try to log in through windows authentication and if that fails, require the user to enter a different set of credentials?

Comment: The downside of this is that anybody sitting at Bob's computer will have access to your application.

Comment: Even worse is that he'll get fired for not locking his computer. But then again, nobody likes Bob anyways :-)

Comment: So yeah, I'd say that's your best bet then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for Windows Authentication and Authorization in ASP.NET

- [How To Use Windows Auth in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx)
- [Authentication/Authorization Explained](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647076.aspx)
- [How To Implement Windows Auth in ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323176)

Part 2...you're right, that's tough. You'll need to roll your own custom security provider. 
You'll have a login page, then check that against Active Directory yourself. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647076.aspx)

> ASP.NET also supports custom solutions
>   for using Windows authentication,
>   which bypasses IIS authentication. For
>   example, you can write a custom ISAPI
>   filter that checks the user's
>   credentials against Active Directory.
>   With this approach you must manually
>   create a WindowsPrincipal object.

Answer (score 2):

You've got requirements around ***authentication*** and ***authorization*** here.

**Authentication**:  The act of confirming identity
**Authorization**:  The act of correlating an identity to a *privilege* (eg Read/Write/Delete)

Windows Authentication is useful if you want "auto-signon" capability.  The site will "know" the user by ID without them having to sign in.

The need for users to login from multiple locations means that you must implement a login page.  This would fulfill your requirement in which one user may sit at another's workstation and log in.

You will want to authenticate users against the Windows domain.  This can be done with a custom membership provider.  Here's a walkthrough:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890(v=vs.80).aspx

This will allow you to present a login page that will authenticate users with their domain username and password.  This will ***authenticate*** users- the identity of the user will be stored in the `HttpContext.User`. You can then also maintain a user list in a database to store ***authorization*** data.

Answer (score 0):

Also found this -- a pretty good resource for anybody out there who's in the same boat:

Mixing Forms and Windows Security in ASP.NET

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx